# Storing data in user's own Google Drive account

Tags: google-app-engine, google-docs

Is there a way to get Google App Engine to store data in the current user's own Google Drive account?

The reason behind this is that I want to write a couple of apps that users might not be happy to have stored in a Datastore / Cloud Storage solution that someone else has access to. One example is personal health information like weight and another one is bank account and transaction information.

If I could store it in the user's own google docs account then I wouldn't have access to it and would not be able to see it.

I have found these docs:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/howto/usinggdataservices

but nothing equivalent for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doable by using the [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/).

From there you can find [DrEdit](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java), which is a sample Google Drive app written in Java using the Google App Engine.